# How do I include the app.settings file when publishing (from Visual Studio) an Azure WebJob?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a continuous WebJob that I would like to configure to only ever have a single instance.

This is achieved by putting the " {  enableLogs: 1 } " setting in the app.settings file.

What I'm struggling with is the deployment of such a file.

That seems lame...

The same article does suggest using the WebJobs API, but again this isn't built in to the Publish process, so it'd be a manual step or some odd code that runs in the WebJob itself.

I feel I must be missing a way to get this working with the Publish process.

I've had a search around on Google looking for people who have done the same thing but I'm not finding much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please try the following:

- In VS, add the `settings.job` file at the root of your WebJobs console app
- Under the file's properties, mark it as Copy if newer (or Copy always)

And it should get deployed. Find full sample that does that here: https://github.com/davidebbo-test/WebAppWithWebJobsVS.

Comment: Ahhh yes, of course ... heh I feel rather silly for having to ask now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I added the settings.job into my respective bin folders for each web job + "Copy Always" setting - then did an Azure Publish from Visual Studio.  Worked a charm.

Needed to restart my Azure App for this to pick up.

Comment: Don't ever put files into bin folders manually. It will bite you back. Put the file along with your other code, and use copy always (as you said).